# how to wait for local store value in <svelte:head> in sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749765/svelte-how-to-wait-for-component-render) about how to wait for component render but it is not working in case of svelte:head

this is my code

```js
<svelte:head>

    {#if $theme === 'dark'}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{assets}/smui.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{assets}/smui-dark.css" media="screen" />
    {:else if $theme === 'light'}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{assets}/smui.css" />
    {:else}
        <!-- SMUI Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{assets}/smui.css" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="{assets}/smui-dark.css"
            media="screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
        />
    {/if}
```

the issue is that the site will load with the last option (else) and then will choose the first or second after reading the store.

this leads to site flicker.
so how do I force the site t wait for the value?

Comment: This sounds like what I have asked recently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71808370/ssr-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-conditional-rendering-with-store Dynamic rendering doesn't seem to work with Stores. I ended up doing it another way as SSR is needed for what I wanted. If you want to just render it for the client, you could render it client side only.

Comment: Also, personally, I wouldn't render any CSS like that. You could import CSS files to __layout.svelte, and it should work & much faster on the production build. Furthermore, if that's just for loading CSS, you could just import it dynamically.

Comment: did this as in their site [instructions](https://sveltematerialui.com/SVELTEKIT.md). how I make the other method, please note that this is two files and applied as per user preference (dark|light).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you control these stylesheets, use `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {` in native css.

For example:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  .coolClass {
    background-color: white;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .coolClass {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

As mentioned in a comment, your current solution won't work as this type of rendering is very discouraged in svelte.

In your case, wrap your dark stylesheet in `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {}` and keep your spreadsheet normal, since this is your  import order in your HTML

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is already done in the last condition (the last else will use `prefers-color-scheme`.
I solve this issue by using cookies and hooks. the site will load fluently with no flash, check this [video](https://youtu.be/5A21S5mMijI) for details.